# Why won't eclipse app instance run in https

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, ssl

I am maintaining a servlet application previously developed in Eclipse Helios.  I have the servlet instance war file and it runs fine in my Tomcat 7.0 on windows and I receive the correct web responses in SoapUI.  It runs with SSL encryption and the url in SoapUI states;

```
https://localhost:8443/ProjectName/etc/etc
```

But after retrieving the original code from SVN into Eclipse Helios, I can get it to start okay running through the imported Tomcat but it does not seem to start using SSL in Eclipse Helios and the URL in the Eclipse tab states;

```
http://localhost:8000/ProjectName/etc/etc
```

And so when I attempt to run a web request in SoapUI it reacts like the servlet instance is not running.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the server in Eclipse and add it again and now everything appears to be working.  Thanks to all who viewed and inputted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    This solution is supplied for MAC, can follow the same strategy for windows as well.

    Step 1) Generate the certificate with java keytool utility by navigating to bin folder of java installation directory

    LM-MAA-22004958:etc rkala$ cd /Applications/corona-java-1.1.0/jdk-7u45-macosx-x64/Contents/Home/bin 
    LM-MAA-22004958:bin rkala$ keytool -genkey -alias myappcert -keyalg RSA -keystore myapp.keystore
    Enter keystore password:  
    Re-enter new password: 
    What is your first and last name?
      [Unknown]:  localhost.xyz.com
    What is the name of your organizational unit?
      [Unknown]:  my
    What is the name of your organization?
      [Unknown]:  my
    What is the name of your City or Locality?
      [Unknown]:  my
    What is the name of your State or Province?
      [Unknown]:  my
    What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
      [Unknown]:  my
    Is CN=localhost.xyz.com, OU=my, O=my, L=my, ST=my, C=my correct?
      [no]:  yes

    Enter key password for <myappcert>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):  

    Step 2): Copy the generated myapp.keystore file to tomcat /conf directory

    LM-MAA-22004958:bin rkala$ mv myapp.keystore /Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/conf 
    LM-MAA-22004958:bin rkala$ cd /Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/bin
    LM-MAA-22004958:bin rkala$ ./startup.sh 
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /Applications/corona-java-1.1.0/jdk-7u45-macosx-x64/Contents/Home
    Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

    Hit the browser with url https://localhost:8443 and you are good to go

    Step 3) Modify both server.xml with the same config provided below

    1.Tomcat server.xml -> Path: /Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/conf/server.xml
    2.Under eclipse workspace server folder,modify the server.xml here as well

    Add the tls config below this section of commented code. I used port 8443 for https

     <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
             and responses are returned. Documentation at :
             Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
             Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
             APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
             Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
        -->
       <Connector
            SSLEnabled="true"
            clientAuth="false"
            keyAlias="myappcert"
            keystoreFile="/Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/conf/myapp.keystore"
            keystorePass="password which you supplied while generating the certificate using keytool"
            maxThreads="200"
            port="8443"
            scheme="https"
            secure="true"
            sslProtocol="TLS"
     /> 


    Step 4) Catalina policy permission:

    Modify the catalina.policy file located in /conf folder of tomcat installation directory

    Search for below keyword(grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar) and replace all the code with single line as mentioned below

    grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {
          permission java.security.AllPermission;
    };

Step 5) Modify the eclipse.ini file and add the below entries and then restart the eclipse.

-vmargs
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/rkala/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.93/conf/myapp.keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password which you supplied at step 1

    Now you should be able to launch the application and will be able to access it via https
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to running tomcat from within Eclipse. By default the server instances managed by Eclipse (projects in their own right) each have their own separate copies of the tomcat config files (server.xml, context.xml, tomcat-users.xml etc) based on the locally installed runtime version selected at creation. So if the SSL connector is not enabled within that configuration then it won't be started. This allows you to have more than one tomcat instance running at the same time, each with a different config.

To edit the configuration for an Eclipse managed tomcat instance, look for **Servers** in the project explorer, open your instance and edit the **server.xml** to uncomment the SSL connector tag which will look something like:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

You may also need to create a keystore for tomcat if you haven't already - see the docs for more info: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html.

Restart tomcat from within Eclipse and try the secure address. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tombola82.  Yes, running Tomcat from within Eclipse.  Also, yes, this is why I am so confused.  You see I am actually transferring from a PC to a laptop and all worked fine on the PC.  I have the "connector" tag already set up in the server.xml file in both the one in Tomcat\conf and in the server.xml file spawned within Eclipse.  I also have a keystore setup and the SSL certificates imported.  The instance appears to start okay in Eclipse but SoapUI reacts like it is not running.

Comment: Can you browse to it running on the eclipse-tomcat instance on the secure address outside of SoapUI, or does that fail too?

Comment: When I start the instance in eclipse-tomcat and attempt to go to the URL in IE I was initially warned of a certificate error and accepted risk but it still gives the same output in soapUI afterwards

Comment: Sounds like a SoapUI SSL trust issue then - you can configure keystores / truststores etc in the Settings and Preferences I think; maybe look in the SoapUI response log first to confirm what's going on.

Comment: I have this resolved.  Thanks for your input.  I removed the server in Eclipse and added it again and it all seems fine.